# Firebase enviar Datos

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview

Buenas Tardes,

Tengo este problema, estoy separando en capas el proyecto y cuando quiero obtener los datos y enviarlos a la capa interfaz para que se muestre  en un `recyclerView`retorna vacío , y nunca me lo carga y tengo que usar variables `static` y llamarlas de la capa interfaz para que me lo cargue, pero no es correcta esa programación.

¿Cual puede ser el problema o cual puede ser la solución?

Pongo el método que debería devolver el `ArrayList` : `ArrayList<amigo> listaAmigos;`

```
public ArrayList<amigo> getAmigos(String email)
{
    String delimitadores = "@";
    String[] emailCortado =email.split(delimitadores);
    DatabaseReference amigos = ref.child("amigos").child(emailCortado[0]);
    amigos.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            amigo sss = dataSnapshot.getValue(amigo.class);
            listaAmigos.add(sss);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return listaAmigos;
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias,
Espero su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

Firebase tiene una libreria [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) que incluye `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` además de otra serie de cosas.
En tu caso podrías utilizar dicho adapter para tu `recyclerView`

Aquí te dejo un [ejemplo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) en la que hace uso de distintos tipos de listas utilizando la librería de `FirebaseUI`.

Espero que te sea útil.